# Node.js Equivalent of Java String getBytes ISO_8859_1

Tags: java, node.js, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I'm trying to port some code from Java to Node.js, and I've run into a little trouble.

Given the String `"645553dd"` in Java, I can extract a series of bytes using `.getBytes("ISO_8859_1")` that looks like `{ 54, 52, 53, 53, 53, 51, 100, 100 }`.  However, I'm having a hard time doing the same in Node.js.  I tried using buffers, converting to the similar ASCII charset, but no luck.  I tried using [node-iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv), but it kept throwing the error `EILSEQ, Illegal character sequence`.  How can I get the same set of bytes in Node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to convert from the Buffer's [default encoding](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_str_encoding) of `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1` with `iconv`:

```
var Iconv  = require('iconv').Iconv;
var ic8859 = new Iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');

console.log( ic8859.convert(new Buffer('645553dd')) );
```

Note that the values are output in base-16 -- `0x64 == 100`:

```
<SlowBuffer 36 34 35 35 35 33 64 64>
```

---

If you're still getting a `EILSEQ` error, then your strings contains a character code that isn't supported by `ISO-8859-1`. You'll either have to [translate or ignore](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv#dealing-with-untranslatable-characters) these characters:

```
var ic8859 = new Iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE');
```

Or try a different encoding, like [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

```
console.log(new Buffer('645553dd'));
// <Buffer 36 34 35 35 35 33 64 64>
```